# filter out elements on click

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that display a bunch of data with different status.Each data is wrap up on different div.I also have a menu bar that suppose to show ONLY the elements that are bind with that action. I want to be able to hide elements that are not associate with onclick action.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="new">
    <section>
        <ul>
            <li {{action 'showAllLeads'}} {{bind-attr class="allLeadsTabIsActive:activeMenuTab"}}>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-menu"></i>ALL
                </a>
            </li>
            <li {{action 'newLeads'}} {{bind-attr class="newLeadsTabIsActive:activeMenuTab"}}>
                <a href="#">TWO</a>
            </li>
            <li {{action 'activeLeads'}} {{bind-attr class="activeLeadsTabIsActive:activeMenuTab"}}>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-right-open"></i>ONE
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</script>


App.NewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        showAllLeads: function(){
            this.send('resetTabs');
            this.set('allLeadsTabIsActive', true);
        },
        activeLeads: function(){
            this.send('resetTabs');
            this.set('activeLeadsTabIsActive', true);
        },
        newLeads: function(){
            this.send('resetTabs');
            this.set('newLeadsTabIsActive', true)
        },
        resetTabs: function(){
            this.set('allLeadsTabIsActive', false);
            this.set('newLeadsTabIsActive', false);
            this.set('activeLeadsTabIsActive', false);
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you throw this into a jsbin? Are you looking for something like this http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_sortBy ?

Comment: as you can see I have a menu bar which is my handlebar template every time i click one of those buttons i want to be able to hide elements not associated with that buntton. A great example will be something like this $('button').click(function(){ $('.hideDiv' ).hide();  });

Comment: Thats not sorting thats filtering. What does your model look like?

Comment: yes filtering...Sorry about that sometimes I can't find words to explain things properly....

Comment: You probably need http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make a route for every tab. Because your doing state changes in your controller and I believe those should be in your router (which is a state machine).

I'd expect a router that looks something like:

```
this.route('leads', function() {  //all leads
  this.route('new');              //new leads
  this.route('active');           //active leads
});
```

That being said. You can easily update the active tabs, by doing something along these lines:

I'm asuming your tabs are in your `model`

```
App.NewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    activeTabs: function() {
        if (this.get('newLeads') {
            return this.get('model').filter(function(lead) { 
                return lead.get('isNew'); 
            });
        }
        //etc, etc, etc
    }.property('model', 'allLeads', 'newLeads', 'activeLeads');
});
```

Make sure you use the property `activeTabs` in your templates, instead of model.

Comment: this work fine, if the content on each view have many actions. Since i only want to hide a couple of divs i came with a better solution that only manipulate the Dom and hide the elements via CSS......Anyways this answer works as well but for my purpose i wanted something more simple...Thank you anyways.........